# JSF, Hibernate, and Spring web application architecture

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, design-patterns, architecture

I started my first web project using JSF, Hibernate and Spring and I would like to know if the architecture that I designed is the most appropriate. 
The beans are annotated with @Controller, and the InventoryServiceImpl is annotated with @Service. I also use @Autowired for dependency injection. The AbstractDao has the Hibernate's SessionFactory attribute (**it's not ServiceFactory as it says in the image, sorry about that**) which is responsible for the access to the database itself, so the DAO's Implementations just calls methods of the AbstractDao superclass.

My concern is mainly regarding the Service, as I am not sure if only one class that accesses all DAOs is the wisest thing to do.

The UML diagram:
[uml-diagram http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1280x1024q90/673/ebfa7f.png](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1280x1024q90/673/ebfa7f.png)

Any comments or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: My opinion if it is good for you than it is not big deal. In case you have many business logic for any type of your entities than it is should be more clear to have one service per dao.
And how did you use jsf in your project?

Comment: Regarding to service, it depends on how you want to scale your application, but IMO it's better to implement more than one service, just to avoid having only a service class with thousands of lines in the future. Apart from that, I consider this question too broad to be suitable for stack overflow. It has many possible good answers...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about design. It's probably a better fit for programmers.se

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Sorry, I didn't know that this kind of question wasn't suitable for stackoverflow. I appreciate the comments, though. @alexSunder I use JSF on my html pages (mainly with the tags), but somethings were kind of replaced with Spring, like the Managed Beans. Is this correct? I am very new to JSF and Spring, this is my first project.

Comment: There are many good tutorials and explanations in web. JSF+Spring integration http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/ Be aware about jsf and spring bean scopes http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-bean-scopes-examples/ http://balusc.blogspot.ru/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ManagedBeanScopes